# Spring batch state persistance

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am using Spring batch in my application for the first time.
Basically my application reads multiple CSV files and do some processing.

After it reads every CSV file it moves the CSV file to some other folder in the same system.
My problem is if my application is stopped due to some failure. And if it's in the middle of reading some CSV file, then if I restarts the application it should continue to read from the line where it stopped.

I read the documentation and found Execution status can maintain the state of the application. But couldn't find anywhere how to use it.

How can I persist how many lines are read in the CSV file and how the application can extract this data to continue from where it stopped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the out of the box components (`MultiResourceItemReader` and the `FlatFileItemReader`) along with a relational database, this should "just work".  The metadata will be stored in the database automatically (what file it's on and what row within the file).